# How to get the timestamp range when the count of unique label changes

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am new to Prometheus and hope to solve this problem. Would it be possible to get the timestamp range when the count of unique labels changes?

For example, if I wanted to count the unique label values, I can do the following:

```
count(count by (a)(some_instant_vector))
```

Suppose the query result above looks something like this:

[image: Start ts of unique count label change]

[image: End ts of unique count label change]

In this case, I'd like to get Thu, 08 Feb 2024 00:12:11 GMT and Thu, 08 Feb 2024 01:09:46 GMT as the result.

What are the prom queries that I can make to get these two timestamp values given the count unique label result changes?

Thanks!